# simplifying rxjs code that returns multiple values from simple json

Tags: angular, rxjs

First time writing rxjs code, so I stole some very reasonable looking code [from here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abcqen) to start with.
It went downhill quickly when I adapted it to my needs.  The result ([in this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-55xqt4?devtoolsheight=60)) actually works, but geez its ugly.

What's ugly about it?  It reprocesses the exact same http response 3 times, once for a different section of the exact same health check response json -- surely something that could be avoided with a little more rxjs magic.

So to better learn rxjs I could use some help making it more rxjs-ish.

My requirement is to parse the UP or DOWN statuses from the sutApp, wirmock and h2 in this http response (from spring boot actuator):

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "details": {
    "h2": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "sutApp": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "wiremock": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 1005128249344,
        "free": 926024794112,
        "threshold": 10485760
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code for one of my three passes -- this one captures the h2 health check.

```
const source_h2 = of(  getHealthCheck() ).pipe(
      map(
        (response: {details: {h2: {status: string} } } 
          ) => response.details.h2.status),
);
```

I've got two more blocks of code like this, unadulterated boilerplate, that grab the "status" for the other two healthchecks, wiremock and h2.

To get rid of the ugly, I looked at two different approaches to get all three "status" values in one pass, perhaps returning something like [UP, UP, UP].

First, I found this bit about [groupBy](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html).  It initially looked helpful, but my hopes were dashed when I noticed all the grouping in groupBy was done on either numbers or string -- and the data I needed to retrieve (wiremock, h2, and sutApp) are all objects.  Perhaps there is some way to group by the "status" ?  I couldn't figure it out.

Then I looked at [this on returning multiple values](https://medium.com/@aurimasdarguzis/return-multiple-values-from-observables-in-rxjs-b5277ae22ecd), which also sounded initially promising.  When I looked closer, all the calls to .next() were done in an observer, and I couldn't figure out where to add those calls.

Thanks in advance for any help :-).

Comment: Your question is not really related to rxjs. All you want to do is to transform this "big" JavaScript object into a smaller JavaScript object.So all you need is the map() operator, and a function transforming the object into a smaller one, that has the structure you want. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

function getHealthCheck() {
  return {
    status: "UP",
    details: {
      h2: { status: "UP" },
      sutApp: { status: "DOWN" },
      wiremock: { status: "UP" },
      diskSpace: {
        status: "UP",
        details: {
          total: 1005128249344,
          free: 926641082368,
          threshold: 10485760
        }
      }
    }
  };
}

const rArray: Observable<string[]> = of(getHealthCheck()).pipe(
  map(
  (response: {[key: string]: any}) => {
    const data = response.details;
    let temp: string[] = [];
    for(let key of ['h2', 'sutApp', 'wiremock']) {
      temp.push(data[key].status);
    }
    return temp;
  }),
);

rArray.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

**EDIT**

or:

```
const rArray: Observable<string[]> = of(getHealthCheck()).pipe(
  map(
  (response: {[key: string]: any}) => {
    const data = response.details;
    const keys = ['h2', 'sutApp', 'wiremock'];
    return keys.map(key => data[key].status);
  }),
);

rArray.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Very elegant, here is a stackblitz with Showy's answer:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wzzjr2